# Android Studio Transition not working in tested device

Tags: android, android-studio, transition

Good day, I just started playing around with android studio, I'm stuck on applyng transition in any layout or scene.
I've followed exactly the program in this site

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Transition_Tutorial_using_beginDelayedTransition

This is my .java code:

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.transitiondemo;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.ChangeBounds;
import android.transition.Transition;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.BounceInterpolator;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TransitionDemoActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ViewGroup myLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transition_demo);

        myLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

        myLayout.setOnTouchListener(
                new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
                        handleTouch();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void handleTouch() {
        View view = findViewById(R.id.myButton1);

        Transition changeBounds = new ChangeBounds();
        changeBounds.setDuration(3000);
        changeBounds.setInterpolator (new BounceInterpolator());

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(myLayout,changeBounds);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(myLayout);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        params.width = 500;
        params.height = 350;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_transition_demo, menu);
        return true;
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here is my .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TransitionDemoActivity"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/myButton1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The objective of this program is to move the button from top left to bottom right, then resize it. The tutorial explains that there should be a 'slow' animation or maybe transition after the background layout has been touched. but it is way to instantenous. (it does move and resize, no error at all)

tried other project where Transition is involved e.g :
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-android-transitions--cms-21640

but the app stopped working.

Is my program (above) actually wrong? or it's correct and there is some possible internal error?
please pardon my newbie's question, and please notify me if I made any mistake while asking this first question of mine.

here is my logcat (verbose):

```
02-10 08:33:16.921  30478-30478/com.ebookfrenzy.transitiondemo D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-10 08:33:16.981  30478-30478/com.ebookfrenzy.transitiondemo I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.02
    Build Date: 01/20/14 Mon
    Local Branch: PMH2-KK_3.5-RB1-AU61-554722-586267-set2
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
02-10 08:33:17.011  30478-30478/com.ebookfrenzy.transitiondemo D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-10 08:33:17.061  30478-30478/com.ebookfrenzy.transitiondemo I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@428b96c8 time:82126736
02-10 08:34:24.061  30478-30478/com.ebookfrenzy.transitiondemo I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch Down
02-10 08:34:24.091  30478-30478/com.ebookfrenzy.transitiondemo I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: logcat added, is it correct?

Comment: no errors detected in your log